# Test variable from models

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using IONIC 4 and I have a situation that sounds silly, but I'm stuck with it.

I have a model class like this:

```
export class Media {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public description: string;
  public episode: number;
  public startDate: string;
  public endDate: string;
  public slates: any[];

  constructor() {
    this.id = 0;
    this.name = "";
    this.description = "";
    this.startDate = "";
    this.endDate = "";
    this.episode = 1;
    this.slates = [];
  }
}
```

I open a modal to insert this media when I click in a button:

```
  async goToNewMediaForm() {
    const newMediaModal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: MediaNewPage
    });

    newMediaModal.present();
  }
```

It opens up the insert page for media, based in the Class I posted below and everything works fine.

Now, I want to do something when the user gets out of this modal, so I'm using something like this:

```
async goToNewMediaForm() {
    const newMediaModal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: MediaNewPage
    });

    newMediaModal.onDidDismiss().then(data => {
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward("slate-list");
    });
    newMediaModal.present();
  }
```

So, what I do is move the user to the other page. But I have to have a way to differentiate if the user clicked save or just clicked out of the modal, thus closing it. I just want the user to be forwarded to the next page if he clicked save, not cancelled the modal.

When I console.log the data parameter, I have this:

```
{data: Media, role: undefined}
data: Media
id: 23
name: "eeeee"
description: ""
startDate: ""
endDate: ""
episode: 1
slates: []
__proto__: Object
role: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

When the user clicks the cancel button on the modal:

```
{data: undefined, role: undefined}
data: undefined
role: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

And when the user clicks outside of the modal:

```
{data: undefined, role: "backdrop"}
data: undefined
role: "backdrop"
__proto__: Object
```

I tried to test if the data is of type Media, if is instance of Media, no success..

```
      console.log(data instanceof Media); //False
      console.log(typeof data); //object
      console.log(data === undefined); //False
      console.log(data === "undefined"); //False
      console.log(data == undefined); //False
      console.log(data == "undefined"); //False
```

What I'm missing? How can I test this "data" variable if it's an object even when the user clicks out of the modal or in the cancel button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal needs to be closed before you can procceed in the app. This is stated in the documentation:

> A Modal is a dialog that appears on top of the app's content, and must
>   be dismissed by the app before interaction can resume.

[ion-modal documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal)

---

> I just want the user to be forwarded to the next page if he clicked
>   save, not cancelled the modal.

You can specify a custom role to dismiss the Modal or specify data to achieve the same thing. See the example below to pass a `save` role to your page and trigger the navigation. When you dismiss the modal by clicking outside the modal page for example, the role is set to `backdrop`.

**modal**

```js
this.modalController.dismiss(undefined, 'save');
```

**page**

```js
newMediaModal.onDidDismiss().then((data: object) => {
  if (data['role'] === 'save') this.navCtrl.navigateForward("slate-list");
});
```

Comment: Great, Tomas. That's what I needed.

Comment: Happy to help ;)